# What is wrong with this program Not iterating through the array

Tags: javascript

Why is program not iterating through the array ! The menu.length is 4 still the for loop is iterated only once ! This is my first post in stack overflow So sorry If it is so egregious !

```js
var menu=["Electrical calulator","Light Calulator","Finance Calculator","temperature calculator"];


console.log(menu.length);
for(var i=0;i<menu.length;i++)
{
 console.log(i);
 var li=document.createElement("li");

 var a=document.createElement("a");
 var i=document.createElement("i");
 i.className = "icon mdi mdi-home";
 var span=document.createElement("span");
 console.log(menu[i]);
 span.innerHTML=menu[i];
 a.appendChild(i);
 a.appendChild(span);
 li.appendChild(a);
 document.getElementById('menu_bar').appendChild(li);
}
```

```html
<div id="menu_bar"></div>
```

Comment: count how many times you used `i` as a variable

Comment: beside the double use of `i`, whta do you want with `<i>`, `<a>` and `<span>`? please add in html (source) the wanted result.

Comment: You used `i` for iterator and `var i` again for `document.createElement("i");`

Comment: check console if your js code does not work. there should be some error message. when i run your script i get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
    at window.onload`

Comment: Please check my below answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are redefining the `i` variable here:

```
var i=document.createElement("i");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You just need to change for loop variable cause it is a conflict with other i.

```
var menu=["Electrical calulator","Light Calulator","Finance Calculator","temperature calculator"];


console.log(menu.length);
for(var j=0;j<menu.length;j++)
{
    console.log(j);
    var li=document.createElement("li");
    var a=document.createElement("a");
    var i=document.createElement("i");

    i.className = "icon mdi mdi-home";
  var span=document.createElement("span");
    console.log(menu[j]);
    span.innerHTML=menu[j];
    a.appendChild(i);
    a.appendChild(span);
    li.appendChild(a);
    document.getElementById('menu_bar').appendChild(li);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using var i for iteration and var i element creation. Change iteration i to index.

Answer (score 0):

Beside the double use of `i`, it's now `j`, you need to append the nodes in the right order to get an `<ul>` with the right children `<li>`.

```
<ul id="menu_bar">
    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon mdi mdi-home"><span>Electrical calulator</span></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon mdi mdi-home"><span>Light Calulator</span></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon mdi mdi-home"><span>Finance Calculator</span></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon mdi mdi-home"><span>temperature calculator</span></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

```js
var menu = ["Electrical calulator", "Light Calulator", "Finance Calculator", "temperature calculator"],
    j,
    li, a, i, span;

for (j = 0; j < menu.length; j++) {
    li = document.createElement("li");

    a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href= '#';
    i = document.createElement("i");
    span = document.createElement("span");

    i.className = "icon mdi mdi-home";

    span.innerHTML = menu[j];
    i.appendChild(span);
    a.appendChild(i);
    li.appendChild(a);
    document.getElementById('menu_bar').appendChild(li);
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu_bar"></ul>
```